# How do I make a table with a summary at the bottom?

Tags: r, gt

I have searched high and low for a way to simply put a summary at the bottom of an output table. It should be very simple, but I am not that experienced, and for some reason I am not able to make gt/gtsummary work. For instance, with this example from rstudio.com:

```r
# Create a gt table using the `exibble` dataset
exibble_a <-
  exibble |>
  select(-c(fctr, date, time, datetime)) |>
  gt(rowname_col = "row", groupname_col = "group") |>
  sub_missing()
exibble_a
```

I get this error message

```
Error in select(exibble, -c(fctr, date, time, datetime)) :
  unused argument (-c(fctr, date, time, datetime))
```

https://gt.rstudio.com/articles/creating-summary-lines.html

Could someone please help me?

Kind regards,
J

Comment: Check to make sure the `select(..)` you're using is the right one: type in `select` and confirm that the output includes `namespace:dplyr`, if not then you have "masking". For instance, there is also `raster::select` (likely others).